# Site works ok on HTTP, not on HTTPS

Tags: https, apache2, http, httpd.conf

I have the following on sites-enabled: 
000-default.conf
default-ssl.conf

000-default.conf has:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.optonet.inter.edu
    ServerAdmin webmaster@opto.inter.edu
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/joomla

    <Directory /var/www/html/joomla>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

default-ssl.conf has:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName www.optonet.inter.edu
        ServerAdmin webmaster@opto.inter.edu
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/joomla

        SSLEngine on
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            Options -Indexes
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile    **********************
        SSLCertificateKeyFile **********************
    </VirtualHost>
    SSLStaplingCache shmcb:/tmp/stapling_cache(128000)
</IfModule>
```

When I go to http://www.optonet.inter.edu and any subpage it opens ok. 
If I try https://www.optonet.inter.edu it opens, but if I try any subpage it shows 404 not found error.

The sites use mod_rewrite and SSL using letsencrypt.

.htaccess has a bunch of redirects, but nothing that refers to http/https

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: eliminated default-ssl.conf and consolidated everything into 000-default.conf 
changed under virtualhost:*80 servername -> servername <url>:80
and under virtualhost:*443 -> servername -> servername <url>:443

same result.

Comment: to debug I'd run `apachectl configtest`, for details see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/apachectl.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you have is because you have not abled `AllowOverride All` within the SSL virtual host which allows the use of `.htaccess` which I suspect contains the URL rewrite rules and conditions.

***Add this code to your SSL virtual host:***

```
# START NEW CODE
<Directory /var/www/html/joomla>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
# END NEW CODE
```

***Your end code should look something like this:***

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName www.optonet.inter.edu
        ServerAdmin webmaster@opto.inter.edu
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/joomla

        SSLEngine on
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>

        # START NEW CODE
        <Directory /var/www/html/joomla>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
            Options -Indexes
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        # END NEW CODE

        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            Options -Indexes
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile    **********************
        SSLCertificateKeyFile **********************
    </VirtualHost>
    SSLStaplingCache shmcb:/tmp/stapling_cache(128000)
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That solved it thanks!  I am still a bit of a novice with Apache!